# String similarity scores for search term

Tags: python

Below is my sample data with its product ID. For a product, if a user enters any related keyword from library and then the most relevant product should be returned on top links. What should be used to find string similarity score. If similarity is 80% then score should be 3, if 50% then 2 if no match 1.

Search Library:
{'100001': ['Bullet01', 'Versatile connector for various 90Â° connections and home repair projects', 'Bullet02', 'Stronger than angled nailing or screw fastening alone', ['Not', 'angles', 'make', 'joints', 'stronger', 'also', 'provide', 'consistent', 'straight', 'corners', 'Simpson', 'Strong', 'Tie', 'offers', 'wide', 'variety', 'angles', 'various', 'sizes', 'thicknesses', 'handle', 'light', 'duty', 'jobs', 'projects', 'structural', 'connection', 'needed', 'Some', 'bent', 'skewed', 'match', 'project', 'For', 'outdoor', 'projects', 'moisture', 'present', 'use', 'ZMAX', 'zinc', 'coated', 'connectors', 'provide', 'extra', 'resistance', 'corrosion', 'look', 'Z', 'end', 'model', 'number', 'Versatile', 'connector', 'various', 'connections', 'home', 'repair', 'projectsStronger', 'angled', 'nailing', 'screw', 'fastening', 'aloneHelp', 'ensure', 'joints', 'consistently', 'straight', 'strongDimensions', 'x', 'x', 'Made', 'Gauge', 'steelGalvanized', 'extra', 'corrosion', 'resistanceInstall', 'd', 'common', 'nails', 'x', 'Strong', 'Drive', 'SD', 'screws'], 'Simpson Strong-Tie 12-Gauge Angle', 'Simpson Strong-Tie 12-Gauge Angle']}

Search Term: {'100001': ['angle bracket', 'l bracket']}

Comment: Shouldn't the data structure be "product": ["search term1", "search term2",  "search term 3"] Why are some items in the list another list

Comment: I have combined several rows from four csv files. Each file contains some data for every product.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can get the similarity between two strings in python

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

string1 = "hello"
string2 = "hellx"

print (SequenceMatcher(None, string1, string2).ratio())

#prints 0.8
```

Comment: Using difflib on my data gives me error. Is there any way to remove all comma, brackets, from above "Search Library" to make data look like a single sentence. In that way difflib would work.

ser_rel = {}  
for k in searchdict:  
    if k in maindict:  
         a = searchdict[k]  
         b = maindict[k]  
         seq=difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a,b)  
         ser_rel[k]=seq.ratio()*100  

here is my code for given data.

Comment: Oh you're working with that data in string format? I assumed it was a list

Comment: yeah, its string stored in dictionary. Please look sample data format in first post